# What happens if you defeat one of the Lake Guardians?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

One of the missions you get after completing the main story is

> Mission 21: The Plate of the Lakes. The objective is to catch Mespirit, Azelf, and Uxie

What happens if you defeat one of these Pokémon instead of catching them? Does the mission become uncompletable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Online ([unofficial](https://www.gamerguides.com/pokemon-legends-arceus/guide/story-walkthrough/missions/mission-21-the-plate-of-the-lakes)) sources state that if you accidentally KO one of the Guardians, it will instantly respawn.

Saving before trying the battle is surely the safest move, in any case.

This is confirmed by OP:

Comment: I hadn't tried myself because Legends autosaves by default and I'd forgotten it could be disabled. I'll to confirm your answer myself and get back.

Comment: @Stevoisiak LOL disabling auto-save was the first thing I looked for

Comment: Confirmed, [the lake guardian will respawn](https://youtu.be/n5EsUk7ANUI). Feel free to use the video in your answer.